# Index Out of bounds on Traveling Salesman

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

I am working on a Traveling Salesman program for my class. My teacher gave us a few text files with various X, Y coordinates for certain cities. My program is working for the files with 10, 100, and 1000 cities. For some reason when I use 13,509 cities the program throws an index out of bounds error after I have sorted 12,022 cities. I can't figure out what the problem is, and I can't recreate the problem on any other smaller city lists (the 10, 100 or 1000 cities). 
My first guess is that something is wrong with my arrayIndex variable but I have no idea why it would stop working at that specific point and why it doesn't happen any other times. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

```
public class TSP_GUI13509 extends JPanel
{

    //ArrayList X, Y for the original City list
    ArrayList<Double> xCoord = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Double> yCoord = new ArrayList<>();
    //ArrayList X, Y for the Final City list
    ArrayList<Double> xCoordFinal = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Double> yCoordFinal = new ArrayList<>();
    //Initialize the shortestDist and distance variables
    double shortestDist = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double distance = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    public TSP_GUI13509(Container pane)
    {
        //sets n to the number of cities
        int n = xCoord.size();

        //Initialize the variables to hold the short City
        double shortX = 0;
        double shortY = 0;

        //Number to place city in the correct position in final array
        int mainCount = 0;

        //Sets the first city to be the first point in the list
        double x1 = xCoord.get(mainCount);
        double y1 = yCoord.get(mainCount);

        try
        {
            //loop through entire array of cities
            while (xCoord.isEmpty() == false)
            {
                //ArrayIndex
                int arrayIndex = 0;

                //Initialize the second city to find the distance
                double x2 = xCoord.get(arrayIndex);
                double y2 = yCoord.get(arrayIndex);

                //loop for 1 iteration of finding the shortest distance
                for (int citiesLeft = xCoord.size(); citiesLeft > 0; citiesLeft--)
                {
                    //Calculates the distance between city 1 and city 2
                    distance = Distance(x1, y1, x2, y2);

                    //distance has to be greater than 0
                    if (distance > 0)
                    {
                        //check for the shortest distance
                        if (distance < shortestDist)
                        {
                            shortestDist = distance;
                            shortX = x2;
                            shortY = y2;
                        }//end if (distance < shortestDist)
                    }//end if (distance > 0)

                    //increment the city index
                    arrayIndex++;
                    if (arrayIndex < xCoord.size())
                    {
                        x2 = xCoord.get(arrayIndex);
                        y2 = yCoord.get(arrayIndex);
                    }// end if (arrayIndex < xCoord.size())
                }// end for - (int citiesLeft = n - 1; citiesLeft >= 0; citiesLeft--)
                shortestDist = Double.MAX_VALUE;

                //Adding the closest city to the final array and removing from the original array
                if (xCoord.contains(shortX))
                {
                    xCoordFinal.add(x1);
                    yCoordFinal.add(y1);
                    xCoord.remove(x1);
                    yCoord.remove(y1);
                }//end if (xCoord.contains(shortX))

                if (arrayIndex >= xCoord.size())
                {
                    x1 = shortX;
                    y1 = shortY;
                    //throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Final = " + xCoordFinal.size() + "\nReg = " + xCoord.size());
                }//end if (arrayIndex >= xCoord.size())

                //increment the city index
                if (arrayIndex == xCoord.size())
                {
                    arrayIndex++;
                }// end if (arrayIndex < xCoord.size())

                System.out.println("\nArrayIndex" + arrayIndex);
                System.out.println("\nCities left " + xCoord.size());
                System.out.println("\nCities complete " + xCoordFinal.size());

            }//end while (int mainCount = 0; mainCount < n; mainCount++)
        }//end try

        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            System.out.println("This is your problem: " + e.getMessage() +
                    "\nHere is where it happened:\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }//End TSP_GUI container pane

    //Distance method. Finds the distance between pt 1 and pt 2
    public double Distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
    {
        distance = Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));

        return distance;
    }//end Distance method
}//end Class TSP_GUI
```

Here is the printStackTrace

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 12022, Size: 12022
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at tsp.TSP_GUI13509.<init>(TSP_GUI13509.java:117)
    at tsp.TSPScreen13509.<init>(TSPScreen13509.java:20)
    at tsp.TSP$4.actionPerformed(TSP.java:158)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3322)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exception stack trace and indicate the line that throws the exception. Please also read [*'How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example'*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and seriously consider reducing your code to such an example.

Answer (score 0):

Just and update. I finally found the problem. It was nothing to do with my loop really. It was a problem with duplicates within my text file. When I found the next closest city I added it to my final Array List of cities and removed it from the main city list. Some of the cities had duplicate x values so when I removed an x value that was duplicated, it removed it twice and that messed up my counts.